# MySQL 5.7: Password not generated on Virtual CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos

i just installed `mysql 5.7` by following the guide in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/), after installing the server, the guide shows that after starting `mysqld` service, i should get the temporary password stored in `/var/log/mysqld.log` by using the following command

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

But this code shows nothing, i even searched the whole file and i don't find it.. i Checked if the service had problems starting, but it seems it's working right, and it even prompts me to enter the root password when i try to access mysqld, of course it denies the access as i don't have the password

Comment: did you solve this yet

Comment: @Drew no, i was not able to solve it, i will get back to my workstation tomorrow

Comment: 57 is cool. you will like it I think

Comment: @Drew is not cool when i am unable to access it

Comment: It took me a while. It was sitting in my error log file. remember general log versus error log. See image ---> http://i.imgur.com/8DJFZ7n.jpg

Comment: @Drew I remember there was no password line in the log, i even used the grep

Comment: You know there is the option in 5.7 to go with the `xxx-insecure` generation right? There are two ways. The way you did it and me too, did the random. The other way would presumably let you get in with just `mysql -u root` . Then you need to make sure `mysqld` is running. But you would have needed to make sure you have the `/Data` dir setup right with the confs. The whole "Db Initialize" thing. Then there is the issue of if `mysqld` is not running, `mysql` cmd line won't really tell you that, just prompt for a password, even though nothing is bound to the port as a server and actually running

Comment: @Drew i tried with `mysld -uroot` but yet it gave access denied.. although i did not try the `xxx-insecure` way, i would try it now but the server terminal can only be accessed through local network

Comment: It is a total PITA but from my angle it is somewhat fun because I need to document the steps to help other people I do work with. But yeah, on your end, not fun. Also note I was doing it on windows. I am about to do it on Linux. Each has a few distros and ways of doing it. The fact that my random password ended up where it did can be quite different than for you.

Comment: @Drew according to the official guide, it should have been regenerated and logged.. but i don't find any place to see what is the password

Comment: I am in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room where I help people. Stop on by sometime. It is 4am and I need to get some sleep though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118674/discussion-between-nosthertus-and-drew).